# UITableView does't scroll after go to another viewcontroller from searchbar result table and come back

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uisearchbar

I have a UITableViewController that show data in cells. In `viewWillAppear` I add a UIView to tableHeaderView with this method `self.tableView.tableHeaderView =headerView;`

In `headerView` I add a UISearchBar and a UISegmentControl programmatically. I set UISearchBar delegate like this

```
self.searchDisplay.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplay.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplay.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplay.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
```

the `searchDisplay` is `UISearchDisplayController`.

The search is work perfectly but my problem is when I select one cell from `searchResultsTableView` and go to another viewController when touch back button in UINavigationController and come back to this view the table doesn't scroll anymore.

I add this two method in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`  but still doesn't work

```
self.tableView.bounces = YES;
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

It's work perfectly when I select one row from table without search and go and come back.

What's the problem ?

Comment: what you have in didSelectRowAtIndexpath: method

Comment: @R.A : I have this method performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:

Comment: move your `viewWillAppear` code to `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using two tableviews on the view, (`self.tableView` and `self.searchDisplay.searchBarTableView`) one for showing data, and one for showing the searched data. I think the searchViewController is staying on the screen after the segue.

There's a trick to show the whole data and search results in a single tableView (no need to use `UISearchDisplayController`)

Just do the following to show the search results:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

for the actual data, you can empty the `UISearchBar` and load the whole data in table view datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your

```
self.tableView.bounces = YES;
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

in `- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` instead of `viewDidLoad`. I believe `viewDidLoad` doesn't get called when coming back from a other view, only when being created.

Comment: I did it before but nothing happened